# Does fs.writeFile perform sequential or random IO?

Tags: node.js, file-io

I am learning about sequential vs random file IO, and it caught my attention that the Node `fs` documentation does not mention whether `fs.writeFile` functions do sequential or random IO. Same for functions related to reading files.

Maybe its implicit for the file API for the platform to be sequential. Maybe the abstraction decides between sequential or random based on factors like file size, etc. I dont know. Either way, I am newbie in this matter and would love to get more clarity around this topic.

When a developer new to NodeJS takes the `fs` code from the getting started page, what is it really doing? Sequential or random IO? Can we opt for one or the other while using the `fs` API?

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const content = 'Some content!';
fs.writeFile('/Users/joe/test.txt', content, err => {
  if (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
  // file written successfully
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you are asking because you want to know whether you can expect sequential write performance or random write performance (random writes are a lot slower).  So for that, it matters what is happening at the disk controller level and whether other read/writes to other parts of the disk are being interleaved with your read/writes.

Mostly sequential, but it depends...

If you look internally at the [code](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/94156e35dfb2f3c837b664f7a8c84f0a95b32e37/lib/internal/fs/promises.js#L465C16-L465C31), `fs.writeFile()` calls `writeFileHandle()` which writes the data in max chunk sizes defined by this constant:

```
const kWriteFileMaxChunkSize = 512 * 1024;
```

So, for a file that is 512k or less, the file will be written with one call to the OS.  Otherwise, it will be broken up into successive 512k writes.

Now, as to whether this is closer to sequential or random IO, that's a bit more complicated.  If nothing else is happening on the disk by any other process in the OS and the disk is not fragmented, then these successive 512k writes can very much be sequential writes.

But, if the OS is doing other things on the disk in other processes, then the disk heads may be required to move to handle this other process between the multiple writes of `writeFileHandle()` and this would probably behave more like random IO because there would be head seeks to a new part of the disk between each write.  But, since these are still 512k writes (not super small), there's still an aspect of sequential IO to each 512k write.  So, it would probably end up being a combination of mostly sequential, but occasionally random because of other disk activity getting interleaved.

If the disk is heavily fragmented, then all bets are off because even a 512k write may have to put different blocks of that write in non-sequential parts of the disk.

Comment: It is sequential from the point of view of the process, and that's all that matters. You're wildly overthinking this.

Comment: @user207421 - It seems to me that the OP is wanting to know whether they can expect disk performance like sequential writes or random writes.  So, what matters for that is what happens at the disk controller level not at the app level.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @jfriend00. You got my question right. So, the intention of the fs.write* code in NodeJS is for the writes to be as sequential as possible. The random IO portion that may happen is due to interferences from other processes or disk state.

You arrived at your answer by analyzing the fs.write* underlying code. Is there any reference from NodeJS or other sources that describe the sequential intent of this implementation? I couldnt find any.

Comment: @GabrielRobaina - Nobody ever tries to make file writing to a single file into a random operation because that's just slow.  Random IO happens either due to interference from other operations also using the disk, from disk fragmentation or from code that's doing a lot of different things with the disk - not just writing to one file.  Also doing large file writes at once is always more likely to get you closer to the sequential write performance.

Comment: @GabrielRobaina - As for documentation, I don't think there is any.  This is an API.  Whether you get performance closer to sequential performance has more to do with how you use the API than it does with how the API is implemented.  It just does what you tell it to do.  If you tell it to write a super large block of data to a file, it will attempt to write that serially in 512k blocks.  If you tell it to write small blocks to file A and then a small block to file B and then a small block to file C and repeat that over and over again, you will get performance more like random IO.